# Converse of Schur's First Lemma

Tags: representation-theory

Suppose $G$ is a closed subgroup of $SU(d)$, $d>1$, and let $\rho$ be a $d$-dimensional special unitary representation of $G$. Suppose that if a matrix $A$ commutes with all of $\rho(G)$ for all $g\in G$, then $A=cI$. Does it then hold that $\rho$ is an irreducible representation of $G$?

Schur's first lemma states that if $\rho$ is irreducible, then if a matrix $A$ commutes with all of $\rho(G)$ for all $g\in G$, then $A=cI$. I'm asking if the converse of this statement holds. If it doesn't hold in general, does it hold in any special cases? I'm particularly interested in the case where $d=3$ and $G$ is either finite or continuous and closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We'll prove the contrapositive.

Suppose $\rho:SU(d)\to Gl(V^d)$ is reducible.  Then we have a decomposition $V^d = U^m \oplus W^n$ (with $m+n=d$) where both $U^m$ and $W^n$ have positive dimension.  (Representations which preserve $\langle \cdot , \cdot \rangle$ are automatically completely reducible by using orthogonal complements).

Choose a basis $\{u_i\}$ of $U$ and a basis $\{w_j\}$ of $W$, so the set $\{u_i, w_j\}$ is a basis of $V^d$.  In this basis, every $\rho(g)$ will have block diagonal form where the top block is $m\times m$ and the bottom block is $n\times n$.

Now, consider the diagonal matrix $D$ where the first $m$ diagonal entries are $1$ while the last $n$ entries are $2$.  By inspection, this matrix commutes with the block form we just mentioned above.  In particular, we have exhibited a matrix *not* of the form $cI$ which commutes with $\rho(g)$ for all $g$.

Comment: How do we know that $D$ is in the image of $\rho$?

Comment: @QuercusRobur:  It may not be, but whether $D$ is in the image of $\rho$ doesn't affect the proof.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Ok, I see what you mean. The reason for my question is that I was thinking about a related but somewhat different situation. I have shown that any element in the center group $Z(SU(n))$ must be proportional to the identity matrix (with some restrictions on the constant of proportionality). I am trying to conclude, on the basis of this result, that the defining (?) representation, when $\rho(g) = g$, is irreducible. I tried to argue the contrapositive and exhibit an element in $Z(SU(n))$ *not* proportional to the identity.

Comment: I tried to argue that if $\rho$ is reducible, then there exists an invertible matrix $S$ such that $S^{-1}gS$ has a certain block diagonal form for any $g \in SU(n)$. I would then like to use $D' = SDS^{-1}$ as an example of a nontrivial (i.e. not proportional to the identity matrix) element in $Z(SU(n))$. However, for this to work, of course I need to know that $D' \in SU(n)$. Do you know if this proof strategy is sensible or not?

Comment: @QuercusRobur:  This can be made to work.  One way is to recognize that $S$ can be chosen to be in $U(n)$.  In more detail, $SU(n)$ doesn't just act on $\mathbb{C}^5$, it preserves the form $\langle v,w\rangle = \sum_{i=1}^5 v_i \overline{w}_i$.  If the $SU(n)$ action preserves a subspace $U\subseteq \mathbb{C}^5$, then it also preserves the orthogonal complement $U^\bot$.  If we choose orthonormal bases for $U$ and $U^\bot$, the resulting $S$ has columns given by orthonormal vectors, so $S\in U(n)$.  Now, we can pick $D = (1,...,1, -1,....,-1)$ (instead of using $1$s and $2$s as I did) (cont)

Comment: It now follows that $D'\in U(n)$ and that $D'$ commutes with all of $SU(n)$.  We can now "push" $D'$ into $SU(n)$ as follows.  The number $\det(D')$ has a complex $n$-th root $\lambda$.  The matrix $\lambda I \in U(n)$ commutes with $SU(n)$, so $\lambda I\cdot D'$ also commutes with $SU(n)$.  But one can easily verify that $\lambda D'\in SU(n)$.  Lastly, simply note that because $D$ has two distinct eigenvalues, the same must be true of $D'$ and $\lambda D'$.  In particular, $\lambda D'$ cannot be a multiple of the identity matrix.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help! Just to clarify, we can even choose $S$ in $SU(n)$ right? (you write orthonormal, but then $S\in U(n)$ rather than $S \in SU(n)$). If so, I think one could maybe argue as follows also. If $\mathbf{s}_i$ is the i:th column in $S$, then for fixed i,j the matrix $A = \sum_{k \neq i,j} \mathbf{s}_k\mathbf{s}_k^\dagger + i\mathbf{s}_i\mathbf{s}_j^\dagger - i\mathbf{s}_j\mathbf{s}_i^\dagger$ is clearly in $SU(n)$. The matrix $S^{-1}AS$  will have nonzero elements at $(i,j)$ and $(j,i)$. By picking different values of $i,j$, clearly we get different block structures.

Comment: @QuercusRobur:  Yes, $S$ can be chosen to be in $SU(n)$.  That makes the rest of the argument even easier.  When I wrote the comments, I was thinking "pick an othonomral basis for $U$ and $U^\bot$ and let $S$ be the matrix whose columns are these vectors.  Doing this, there is no reason why $\det S = 1$ would have to be true.  But you're right that we can just modify the last basis vector choice by multiplying by $\overline{\det S}$ to get a new conjugating matrix $S\in SU(n)$.  That's definitely a nicer argument than mine!

Comment: Thanks for the clarification (and apologies for the late feedback)!